# GAE: relationship between queue rate and max_concurrent_requests

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm reading the docs about [GAE task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue) and I'm unclear about the relationship (if any) between `rate` and `max_concurrent_requests`. Does `rate` refer to a single request so that e.g. rate=20/s and max_concurrent_requests=10 effectively means max 200 requests/s in total?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 3 parameters :

- `bucket size` ~ the maximum burst rate
- `rate` ~ normal processing rate
- `max concurrent requests` ~ additional concurrency restriction

When a tasks starts executing, it looks at the bucket to check if there is a token or slot free.

- If so, the number of tokens is decreased with one and the task starts executing if there are less than `max concurrent requests` already executing.
- if not, the task will have to wait for a new token/slot to arrive at the speed of `rate`.

If you have a big bucket, it may fill up when traffic is low and e.g. with a bucket size of 20 and a sudden peak in demand, you can start 20 tasks because they all can get a token. Then the bucket is empty and the tasks will be processed at rate speed.

`Max concurrent requests` can additionally limit the burst rate since long running tasks will slow down the whole processing. Without `max concurrent requests`, only the `bucket size` and `rate` determine the processing speed, not the duration of your tasks.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! So does this mean that `max concurrent requests` should be less than `bucket size` to have any effect? Does `max_concurrent_requests=20` make sense with the default  `bucket_size=5`?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. You will burst up to 5 tasks at once if and only if the previous 20 tasks have finished. Otherwise, your bucket will have tokens but the next tasks will not start until the some of the remaining ongoing tasks have finished.

Comment: Hi koma, Just to clarify, when you say " if and only if the previous 20 tasks have finished", it seems in contradiction with " if there are less than max concurrent requests already executing".
This would rather be "if and only if there are less than 20 running tasks" ?
Otherwise, if only one task took "too much" time to finish it will block all the queue. Something I doubt based on my experience.