# How to setup a queue like a semaphore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have setup four queues in my app.

```
queue:
- name: tasks-stage-0
  rate: 475/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 100
    max_doublings: 5
  bucket_size: 100

- name: tasks-stage-1
  rate: 475/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 100
    max_doublings: 5
  bucket_size: 100

- name: tasks-stage-2     <------- !!!!
  rate: 4/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 100
    max_doublings: 5
  bucket_size: 100

- name: tasks-stage-3
  rate: 475/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 100
    max_doublings: 5
  bucket_size: 100
```

tasks_stage_2 is the one queue that is making external calls to an API.  That API has a limitation of 4 calls per second.

When running the scraping, I get quite a bit of error messages from that queue:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException('Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: xx
```

Is it because I am hitting the API more than 4 times a second after all? Do I have the settings correctly? Or why am I getting these Deadline exceeded errors?

**Update:**

```
taskqueue.Task(url='/worker/stage-2', headers=header, payload=json.dumps({'news_url_string':news.key.urlsafe()})).add(queue_name='tasks-stage-2')
```

**Update 2:**

```
Exception on /worker/stage-2 [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 263, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/flask/views.py", line 149, in dispatch_request
    return meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/news/worker/stage2.py", line 16, in post
    OpenCalais.generate_tags_for_news(news_url_string)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/news/opencalais/opencalais.py", line 31, in generate_tags_for_news
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~news-prod/1-0-10.382350631067599473/lib/requests/models.py", line 831, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: The error message you get doesn't seem to imply that you hit the API limit (it's a timeout rather than a 429). You could try to reduce the rate further, and see if that takes care of it, but I'd also investigate API response times.

Comment: You have a good point. Thanks for sharing the `429` error message. I keep getting `403` error though.  But not always, I wonder what the reason is.  I also don't understand why the task doesn't get retried after an exception. Wasn't that the nature of the task?  Maybe I should reduce it to 3 calls per second to be on the safe side and reduce bucket to 3 as well.

Comment: Retries are not only configured in the queue, but also when you enqueue the task, would you mind posting a snippet on how you do that? Another interesting configuration to use would be max_concurrent_requests. You can check more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033610/gae-relationship-between-queue-rate-and-max-concurrent-requests

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have now added a code snippet how I call the task as you had requested.

Comment: It seems like you are adding to the tasks-stage-3 instead of 2... is that right?

Comment: sorry corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the configuration of your queue is a bit off (see references at the bottom to better understand what each value does)

```
- name: tasks-stage-2
  rate: 4/s  # Once per second, add 4 new tokens to the bucket
  max_concurrent_requests: 4  # No more than 4 at a time!
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 100
    max_doublings: 5
  bucket_size: 4  # Only for places each time it's checked
```

References:

- Best explanation out there: [GAE: relationship between queue rate and max_concurrent_requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033610/gae-relationship-between-queue-rate-and-max-concurrent-requests?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Python_Queue_definitions)
- [Token Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket)

Comment: This still doesn't answer the retry thing, though. The configuration in that regard seems ok and I have similar ones working without trouble. Doesn't the logging tell you anything about retrying? (look for stuff like `Will retry slice ###########-# 0 for the 2 time.`)

Comment: That link was very useful. But I'm still thinking rate `1/s` might be wrong. Initially there are 4 tokens in the bucket. Each task grabs one token until bucket is empty. Thats pretty much instant. Then if we fed only 1 token per second into the bucket, the rate goes down to 1 per second instead of 4 per second. Because there is never enough tokens available to do 4 per second. Hence I believe `rate: 4/s` + `bucket_size: 4` and `max_concurrent_requests: 4` should rather do the trick. Don't you think?

Comment: You are right... I updated the answer and added a link to the Wikipedia explanation on it

Comment: Thanks that looks very good. Last problem remains with retrying. I have added the exception I got on a task. and there is no retry. Very strange.

Comment: One more shot at it: Did you check if the task is re-enqueued? (maybe you are not seeing it retry because of time configuration, but it IS enqueued for retry). I'd also try removing the backoff configs to test that out