# App Engine Task Queue losing more than 30% of jobs when concurrency is enabled

Tags: google-app-engine

Here is an update.
I removed the retry limit..maybe that explains why tasks are lost.
I also reduce max concurrent based on Google's suggestions.
Here is the current queue definition:

```
<queue>
    <name>OsmOrderQueue</name>
    <rate>20/s</rate>
    <max-concurrent-requests>10</max-concurrent-requests>
    <bucket-size>100</bucket-size> 
    <retry-parameters>
        <min-backoff-seconds>30</min-backoff-seconds>
        <max-backoff-seconds>30</max-backoff-seconds>
        <max-doublings>0</max-doublings>
    </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

Also, here is the backends definition.  I added a definition to override the default instances.

```
<backend name="osm-backend">
  <class>B8</class>
  <instances>4</instances>
      <options>
    <dynamic>true</dynamic>
    <public>true</public>
  </options>
</backend>
```

But I didnt see any change in the number of instance deployed.  Its always 1.
I did the update with

```
appcfg.cmd update <war directory>
```

This updates the queue definition even when the queue is running.  Thats a cool feature.

Now the situation is unbelievably different.  Now the tasks sit for almost 3000 seconds and then are switched.  I bet I am billed for this time!

```
    2015-03-14 05:06:57.387 /sampleServlet 500 2869079ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=maptest-backend

    E 2015-03-14 05:06:57.387 A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the nex



2015-03-14 05:06:57.386 /sampleServlet 500 2879643ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=maptest-backend
        E 2015-03-14 05:06:57.386 A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the nex

    2015-03-14 05:06:57.384 /sampleServlet 500 2889684ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=maptest-backend
    E 2015-03-14 05:06:57.384 A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the nex
```

2015-03-14 04:47:33.062 /sampleServlet 200 3674187ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=maptest-backend

By the way, the task I am performing has not threading.  It reads from the datastore and cloud storage and writes to big query.  This should be the most common model in app engine I would think.  If I run one of these tasks by itself,it normally completes in about 200-300 seconds.  Unbelievable slow for B8 machine. I can process on my PC the reading of the same file and it takes about 10 seconds.  I wish I could see an error in my task or queue definition, but I cannot.  How can the peformance be so poor?  How it be so subtle how to configure a task queue?  I am at a loss of understanding...

I am trying to get jobs done in parallel using a task queue with the following configuration.

```
<queue>
    <name>OsmOrderQueue</name>
    <rate>1/s</rate>
    <max-concurrent-requests>8</max-concurrent-requests>
    <bucket-size>4</bucket-size> 
    <retry-parameters>
        <task-retry-limit>7</task-retry-limit>
        <min-backoff-seconds>10</min-backoff-seconds>
        <max-backoff-seconds>200</max-backoff-seconds>
        <max-doublings>2</max-doublings>
    </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

Is it strange that max size is larger than bucket size?

I submitted 100 jobs.  I checked my logs that indeed 100 tasks were entered. I have tried with with only one concurrent session and all tasks were processed.  But here is the kind of error I see.  I see many HTTP codes of 500.  However, the sum is not equal to the lost jobs.  Also, I have a job where bigQuery is not found!!!

Notice that some jobs run almost 5 minutes, which I am paying for, then die and say they are moving to another machine.  But they don't show up.

Strange thing is when I tested this with no-concurrency, they all ran fine.  But I need to speed up the process by running more in parallel. I don't think my servlet has concurrency issues as I looked for exceptions from my code execution and there are none that I can see. So why is Google's task queue failing so much?

Finally, why the URL error reaching bigQuery as shown at the end of the logs below?

```
 2015-03-09 21:42:07.024 /sampleServlet 500 212866ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend

    0.1.0.2 - - [09/Mar/2015:21:42:07 -0700] "POST /sampleServlet HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "https://1-dot-mindful-highway-451.appspot.com/upload" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "osm-backend.mindful-highway-451.appspot.com" ms=212866 cpu_ms=785288 cpm_usd=0.000061 queue_name=OsmOrderQueue task_name=77053872005060790511 exit_code=107 instance=0 app_engine_release=1.9.18 

    W 2015-03-09 21:42:07.024

    Process moved to a different machine.

    2015-03-09 21:42:07.023 /sampleServlet 500 227518ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
    W 2015-03-09 21:42:07.023 Process moved to a different machine.

    2015-03-09 21:42:07.022 /sampleServlet 500 203726ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
    W 2015-03-09 21:42:07.022 Process moved to a different machine.

    2015-03-09 21:42:07.020 /sampleServlet 500 196668ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
    W 2015-03-09 21:42:07.020 Process moved to a different machine.

    2015-03-09 21:42:07.019 /sampleServlet 500 220996ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
    W 2015-03-09 21:42:07.019 Process moved to a different machine.

    2015-03-09 21:41:43.699 /_ah/start 404 3160ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
    I 2015-03-09 21:41:43.699 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

    2015-03-09 21:38:21.758 /_ah/start 404 1968ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
    I 2015-03-09 21:38:21.757 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

    2015-03-09 20:15:51.414 /_ah/stop 200 13ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend 




    2015-03-09 20:04:27.355 /_ah/start 404 2547ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
    I 2015-03-09 20:04:27.355 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

    2015-03-09 20:04:11.770 /sampleServlet 500 241352ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
    W 2015-03-09 20:04:11.770 Process moved to a different machine.



       2015-03-09 20:00:12.995 /_ah/start 404 2154ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
       I 2015-03-09 20:00:12.995 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ



   BIG QUERY FAILED...
   2015-03-09 21:51:06.675 /sampleServlet 200 576506ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend

   0.1.0.2 - - [09/Mar/2015:21:51:06 -0700] "POST /sampleServlet HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://1-dot-mindful-highway-451.appspot.com/upload" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "osm-backend.mindful-highway-451.appspot.com" ms=576507 cpu_ms=484901 cpm_usd=0.156302 queue_name=OsmOrderQueue task_name=21675006186640709011 pending_ms=13531 instance=0 app_engine_release=1.9.18 
   2015-03-09 21:51:06.671

   com.example.lifescore.SampleServlet uploadFileToBigQuerry: New table throws exception e:java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/mindful-highway-451/jobs?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UqDHFbMpUsL5m_a88fWh0hnhYzxp20qbbQlHe1mplsiNyo0g0Roktir0Gk5E6yUkBblXrTjz6cxw7aWF3m0dT03Q6CiQA
```

As suggested, I increased the bucket size to 100 and removed the max-concurrent-request line.  It had no impact.  I issued 100 jobs, they were all in the queue, but still run sequentially. I dont see any jobs running in parallel.  This dump shows 86 in queue, but only 6 running.

Queue Name  Maximum Rate    Enforced Rate   Bucket Size     Maximum Concurrent  Oldest Task     Tasks in Queue  Run in Last Minute  Running
OsmOrderQueue   1.0/s   0.10/s  100.0       2015-03-10 18:25:28                     (0:09:45 ago)   86  6   6

But what is interesting is that the failed 500 events seem to come after 
an ahStart.

```
2015-03-10 18:37:16.358 /sampleServlet 500 230964ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:37:16.358 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:37:16.357 /sampleServlet 500 68596ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:37:16.357 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:37:16.355 /sampleServlet 500 88692ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:37:16.355 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:37:16.354 /sampleServlet 500 99255ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:37:16.354 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:36:51.219 /_ah/start 404 2620ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
I 2015-03-10 18:36:51.219 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
```

This came after about 20 perfectly run (but sadly slow, each about 5 minutes)
which came after about 5 500's

```
2015-03-10 18:15:16.894 /sampleServlet 500 114343ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.894 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:15:16.893 /sampleServlet 500 98997ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.893 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:15:16.892 /sampleServlet 500 154237ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.892 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:15:16.891 /sampleServlet 500 139429ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.891 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:15:16.890 /sampleServlet 500 122964ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.890 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:15:16.889 /sampleServlet 500 130682ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.889 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:15:16.888 /sampleServlet 500 163503ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=osm-backend
W 2015-03-10 18:15:16.887 Process moved to a different machine.

2015-03-10 18:14:52.896 /_ah/start 404 2668ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
I 2015-03-10 18:14:52.860 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

2015-03-10 18:12:35.918 /_ah/start 404 2518ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=osm-backend
I 2015-03-10 18:12:35.917 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time.
```

Here is an image of the taskqueue performance littered with contant 500 events with no logging of any errors or exceptions (just moved to another machine)...Pretty poor huh!

I tried to add the image but SO says I need higher reputation.  Can anyone help me there..Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply.  My mistake on using this service wrong.  Let me try to figure out how to accept so I can see you your answer...

Comment: Hi Koma, I cant find a place to say "accept answers.."  that would be helpful to know.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you do **not** specify `<max-concurrent-request>` then all your task queues can execute in parallel as long as there are tokens in your bucket. [I have answered this in detail over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033610/gae-relationship-between-queue-rate-and-max-concurrent-requests/28034679#28034679). You really need to read up on the documentation [over here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue).

> I see many HTTP codes of 500. However, the sum is not equal to the
>   lost jobs.

I can imagine that you see more 500's than scheduled tasks because failed tasks will retry.

> Also, I have a job where bigQuery is not found!!

Expect an occasional glitch when talking to services and think about your retry stratgey. Make sure your calls are [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: I like the idea of removing the max-concurrent-request parameter.  I will try another go with 100 entries.  I agree an occasional glitch is life.  But not 30%.  Also, I find it strange that the 500 error comment is wrong: the task was not moved and restarted..it was lost and no logs of what happened in that task.  I have to deduce which queue entry was lost.  But that is manageable.  Will report back later.

Comment: By the way, my reputation is still below the 15 level required to hit plus on the answer.  Hopefully I will get there soon and be able to.

Comment: @Paul start with bucket-size=1 and <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests> and see all your tasks in sequence processed.

Comment: As I mentioned in the last edit, the suggested failed to run all in parallel.I will try your suggestion of only one at a time...I think I did this before and it was perfect.  I will try it again and report back.  But the sad thing is, there is no logging on what happened to cause a bunch of 500s...are the ahStarts appengine deciding to start another instance?  Why so late?  Also, I think the assumption that removing the restriction would allow all tokens to be processed in parallel doesnt match the observed behavior...

Comment: I dont know why this solution got a +2.  I tried what koma suggested and there was no change in the behavior.  Still lose a lot of data (many 500s).

Comment: I am happy to delete other posts and make 1 post that asks the question:  how to run a bunch of tasks quickly and with a high success rate.  I am getting throttled down by google to 0.1/sec.  I have about 900 tasks sitting in my queue dribbling out at 20-30/hour with about 30% lost to 500's without errors or exceptions.  I have asked to run 100 in parallel on B8's. The task is to read a xml file from the cloud storage, convert to JSON, upload to bigquery.  Files are 3.5MB, 25000 lines and take 5-10min.  Then with 30% lost, I have to run again  Is anyone getting better performance?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two issues here: 1) you are not getting the parallelism you'd expect and 2) your tasks are getting cancelled and moved to other machines.

As to 1:  From what you posted, your settings look correct (once you removed max-concurrent-requests from the queue config).  The queue status line reported the enforced rate at 0.10/s.  I'd expect to see this if the number of instances is capped.  Are you seeing the number of instances increase during processing ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances))?

If you're using Backends, be sure to set the maximum number instances (the 'instances' option); it defaults to one.  Even better, switch to modules since using Backends is deprecated and you'll have more control ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting)).

As to 2: While it's expected to see applications moved, a 30% rate seems high.  I'd expect this to get better after fixing 1.  Follow up on this thread if this continues to be a problem.

Here are some work-around suggestions if you need some short-term ideas:

- Use multiple instances but turn off module multithreading. (this will only allow one of your computations to occur per instance, reducing load but also reducing instance efficiency)
- Checkpoint your results (i.e. save out intermediete results and check for intermediete results on task startup).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  I only see one instance for each queue.  I checked the backends definitoin and there is no instance definition.  I will add this <instances>5</instances>...By the way, I tried modules, but I couldnt figure out how to define the code for each module as I dont see how to point code to the classes folder for each module.  Eclipse can define sources but only to one WAR directory.  There is no teaching about this anywhere.

Comment: @Paul, all modules share the same folder.  What also could help with excessive moves (if David's suggestions don't work) is downgrading your instance class from F4 to F2.

Comment: @Paul: Pavel has a good suggestion.  A smaller instance will both have less running on it if it does get bumped, and will possibly be a smaller target.  You can bump instances up to 20 if you need to.  Please do follow up.

Comment: Thanks David, Pavel, Koma for your helpl.

Answer (score 0):

Better logging showed me the main issue.  I found that each task I was submitting was spending the vast majority of the time inside my main conversion function, not waiting on data from datastore or bigquery.  I dug in and found that I made a pretty junior coding practice mistake, which is, I was concatenating strings to generate the output file, and this caused the task timing to degrade exponentially, up to close to an hour per file.  I wouldnt have believed it , as I had
checked the code before, but at the Google supports suggestion (which was a good one!) to test locally.  I verified that my local code showed the exponential time increase.  Changing to stringBuilder with an sb.append(new line string) and the file = sb.toString().

So with many long running tasks sitting in the queue, I was stressing the queue logic, getting the 500 status for moving to another machine.

When I restructed the code to use a stringBuilder, the same task was done in seconds. In this case, I had no trouble getting 100 tasks to run smoothly and didnt miss any as expected. I managed to have setting working as follows quite well.
            
            OsmOrderQueue
            20/s
            10
            100 
            
                10
                100
                2

I indeed saw up to 10 running in parallel and good performance with
faster running tasks.

However, when you work with big query you learn that the table change limits impact system design.  So I am moving back to larger files, which will mean longer task times, but fewer tasks.  In this case, I wonder if I will start to see the "moving to another machine" phenomenon again.

So I guess, I will state that my task queues work well when tasks are not long.